# How to lookup AD users with pnp-powershell in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, office-365-groups

I have a script that will look up a user based on a folder name and then add that user to the folder permissions with read rights.

Right now I have a few groups setup with explicit user assignment (i.e. manually added to the groups). When i run the below script it works perfectly for those users that are explicitly assigned to those groups. However, when a user does not belong to those groups or are in a nested AD group they are not being found.

How do i get pnp-powershell to "resolve" a user that exists in AD but no explicitly assigned to a SharePoint group? See `$user` variable line for the code i am trying to figure out.

For example. I have a folder named JCANNING that i use `Get-PnPUser | Where Title -Like "*JCANNING*"`. If JCANNING is in the title of a user already explicitly added to the site, it resolves. But if JCANNING happens to be in a an AD group called "All AD Users" it is not found. How can I get it to query the AD users to get the user?

```
    $Url = 'https://SharePoint/Site/Path'
    $Library = 'Team Reports'
    $RootFolder = '/Team Reports/Engineers'

    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Url

    # Get Folders in the Root folder
    $folders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $RootFolder

    # Break Inheritance on each folder and add the user rights
    foreach ($folder in $folders){
        # Get the user based on folder name
        $user = Get-PnPUser | Where Title -Like "*$($folder.Name)*" # Code in Question

        # Break folder inheritance
        $folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($false,$false)
        $folder.Context.Load($folder.ListItemAllFields)
        $folder.Context.Load($user)
        $folder.Update()
        $folder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Host "Inheritance broken for" $($folder.Name) -ForegroundColor Cyan

        # Add Team Editors group to the list and remove all other permissions
        Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $Library -Identity $($folder.ListItemAllFields.Id) -Group 'Team Editors' -AddRole 'Edit' -ClearExisting
        Write-Host "Adding Group 'Team Editors' to folder" $($folder.Name) -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta

        # Add the user based on folder name with Read rights
        Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $Library -Identity $($folder.ListItemAllFields.Id) -User $($user.Email) -AddRole 'Read'
        Write-Host "Adding user" $($user.LoginName) "to folder" $($folder.Name) -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I ended up needing to do if someone else needed something like this

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory #will required to be downloaded/installed

$Url = 'https://SharePoint/Site/Path'
$Library = 'Team Reports'
$RootFolder = '/Team Reports/Engineers'

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Url

# Get Folders in the Root folder
$folders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $RootFolder

# Break Inheritance on each folder and add the user rights
foreach ($folder in $folders){
    # Get the user based on folder name
    $name = $($folder.Name)
    $email = Get-ADUser -Filter{SamAccountName -Like $name}

    # Break folder inheritance
    $folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($false,$false)
    $folder.Context.Load($folder.ListItemAllFields)
    #$folder.Context.Load($user)
    $folder.Update()
    $folder.Context.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "Inheritance broken for" $($folder.Name) -ForegroundColor Cyan

    # Add Team Editors group to the list and remove all other permissions
    Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $Library -Identity $($folder.ListItemAllFields.Id) -Group 'Team Editors' -AddRole 'Edit' -ClearExisting
    Write-Host "Adding Group 'Team Editors' to folder" $($folder.Name) -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta

    # Add the user based on folder name with Read rights
    Set-PnPListItemPermission -List $Library -Identity $($folder.ListItemAllFields.Id) -User $email.UserPrincipalName -AddRole 'Read'
    Write-Host "Adding user" $($email.Name) "to folder" $($folder.Name) -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no PnP native way to do this but you can do it by dropping down into the CSOM EnsureUser method. Try this:

```
$web = get-pnpweb
$user = $web.EnsureUser("user@company.com")
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$ctx.Load($user)
Execute-PnPQuery

$user
```

Comment: Thanks Derek but I need to get the user by searching for part of their "Title". I wont know their email address, that is what i need to look up. Thoughts on that?

Comment: Your example JCANNING looks a lot like a user ID. Is this someone's actual name? I guess I'm confused.

Comment: sorry its not truly a user ID its being stripped from the `Get-PnPUser` title. The full name is "John Canning (JCANNING)". I am just searching based on JCANNING as that is the name of the folder. In short it is the users id (e.g. domain\jcanning) but `$web.EnsureUser` only allows me to lookup based on email or so it seems. I tried domain\username but it did find the user. I tried UPN and it did.

Comment: It's not actually an email although it looks like one. It's a SharePoint Online login ID (which probably is identical to email address but not necessarily). The domain\username pattern will work with EnsureUser for (most) on-premises SharePoint environments, but SPO uses a different pattern. So, if the folder title in the parentheses is actually a user ID you should be able to pass "jcanning@yourcompany.com" into EnsureUser. If that doesn't work for you you're probably going to have to query active directory.

Comment: I got this to work but i had to use the AD module simple enough. I will add an answer with the script i used. Thanks for your help Derek!